# What is a VP Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

<sub>*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™] [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) and [What is a Phrase™] [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee] [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) and the likewise inspired [What is a Number™] [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a certain rule, I call it a VP number and if not, I call it a non-VP number. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| VP Number™ | Not VP Number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |
| 547 | 520 |
| 1297 | 1292 |
| 2027 | 2016 |
| 2749 | 2741 |
| 3593 | 3481 |
| 4421 | 4400 |
| 5281 | 5099 |
| 6217 | 6211 |

For those who want, here is a CSV version

```
VP Number™,Not VP Number™
3,5 
547,520
1297,1292
2027,2016
2749,2741
3593,3481
4421,4400
5281,5099
6217,6211
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is a VP Number™ or a Non VP Number™ on its own. In particular, a number's relationship to other numbers in the sequence is irrelevant.

These are not the only VP-Numbers. More of them exist and can be found.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, any specific reason?

Comment: If I manage to find a valid rule that isn't the same one as the one in your mind, is my answer correct?

Comment: @CipherRiddle let's see what you have got.

Comment: There may be infinitely many valid answers to be pedantic. :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the VP numbers

> are the set of prime numbers whose positions in the sequence of primes are themselves the *first primes in successive prime centuries ([OEIS A157338](http://oeis.org/A157338))*.  <sup>(—thanks OEIS, now I know what to call these!)</sup>
>
>  The first 9 values in that series are 2,101,211,307,401,503,601,701,809.
>  The 2<sup>nd</sup> prime number is 3.
>  The 101<sup>st</sup> prime is 547.
>  The 211<sup>th</sup> prime is 1297.
>  The 307<sup>th</sup> prime is 2027.
>  The 401<sup>st</sup> prime is 2749.
>  The 503<sup>th</sup> prime is 3593.
>  The 601<sup>st</sup> prime is 4421.
>  The 701<sup>st</sup> prime is 5281.
>  The 809<sup>th</sup> prime is 6217.
>
>  Thus, the first 9 VP numbers are those listed in order in the puzzle.

I originally described this as ...

> all *N*<sup>th</sup> prime numbers for each *N* that is the first value in (*k*×100..*k*×100+99) that is prime.
>  In other words, for each set of one hundred numbers (0-99, 100-199, ...), find the first value in that set that is a prime number, and call it *N*; for each such *N*, the *N*<sup>th</sup> prime number is a VP Number.
>
>  The first 9 VP numbers (i.e. *k* in 0..8) are listed in the puzzle:
>  - 3 is the 2<sup>nd</sup> prime number.  2 is the first number between 0 and 99 that is prime.
>  - 547 is the 101<sup>st</sup> prime number. 101 is the first number between 100 and 199 that is prime.
>  - 1297 is the 211<sup>th</sup> prime number.  211 is the first number between 200 and 299 that is prime.
>  and so on.

They are called "VP Numbers" because they are

> [image]
>  <sup>(shamelessly stolen from @lois6b's comment.  I couldn't resist.)</sup>

Comment: [wow, very Prime, much nice](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg)

Comment: Rubio you have 3333 rep, 3 silver badges and 33 bronze :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I apologize for the +1

Comment: I'd like to nominate the joint effort by @lois6b and Rubio for puzzle solution of the year.

Comment: wooooww @feelinferrety thanks.but I only added the meme